# Access: Determine Column Width AFTER Auto-Resize?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an MSAccess datasheet I populate and auto-resize using, stepping thru each column with:

```
~field~.Properties("ColumnWidth") = -2
```

Works just as expected.

Some column widths resolve crazy wide (freeform text, etc.).  I'd like to take a 2nd pass thru the columns and test for these really long ones and reset to some narrower fixed width.  However, when I test for column width, I get a result "-2" (duh) vs the actual resulting width (i.e.,  5760 twips).

Any suggestions how to determine the resulting column width AFTER using auto-resize?

Comment: You said datasheet, that is a form, so you can check the controls, not fields. Do you mean a table or query? If so, you would be better off with a form.

Comment: The datasheet approach is working very well in my DB app, except for those really WIDE columns. I suppose I can predict by name which columns are usually too wide, and resize them explicitly.  I would prefer a generic approach...

Comment: I was not sufficiently clear. Are you using a datasheet, that is, did you create a form?

Comment: Yes, SQL query recordset is source.  Datasheet is embedded in a subform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modified 3/10/2014 (prior code was an EXAMPLE of how to find wide column and set narrower - col. 7 specifically). Using Access 2010 I was able to do what you want -- I think. My Column 7 was REALLY wide (25440) after setting them all (and the debug.print shows the value.  Then I just reset to a number that I liked (i.e. 2000).

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Load()
Dim i   As Integer
On Error GoTo Error_trap
For i = 0 To Me.Form.Controls.Count - 1
    If InStr(1, Me.Form.Controls(i).Name, "_Label") = 0 Then
        If Me.Form.Controls(i).Properties("ColumnWidth") > 2000 Then
            Debug.Print "set " & i & vbTab & Me.Form.Controls(i).Name & vbTab & "From: " & Me.Form.Controls(i).Properties("ColumnWidth") & vbTab & "To: 2000"
            Me.Form.Controls(i).Properties("ColumnWidth") = 2000
        End If
    End If
Next i

'Debug.Print "******  " & Me.Form.Controls(7).Properties("ColumnWidth")

'Me.Form.Controls(7).Properties("ColumnWidth") = 1200

Exit Sub
Error_trap:
   'Debug.Print Err.Number & vbTab & Err.Description & vbTab & i & vbTab & Me.Form.Controls(i).Name
    Resume Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but really looking for a more dynamic approach, in the on load event

Comment: Your code above looks very much like my code, I step thru the controls in the datasheet, hide some columns, and set columnwidth = -2.  When I then re-inspect for column width, I get "-2" as the result, not the actual resulting twips

Comment: 1. What do you mean "more dynamic"? I just used that code as an example to show how it could vary the column sizes. You could use any VBA code you want to test for any number of conditions. You have not mentioned what version of Access you are running, but like I said - I'm 2010.

Comment: <dang CR gets me every time>
2. Have you tried my code in a copy of your form? What does your code look like?

Comment: Wayne, by more dynamic I mean I want to auto-fit the columns to the data during the onLoad event.  Immediately following, I want to inspect for columns widths, setting 2000 twips as the max width.  No effect on columns < 2000 twips.  The data is quite dynamic: I do not know which cols will overrun the desired width.  All of this done during onLoad event - no inspecction of debug.print type results and manual adjustment.

Comment: version 2007 thru 2013 - across my user base.  I do determine and log version number upon login, so I could provide some conditional solution depending on version.

Comment: Hmmm, that's exactly what my code did. My form is a 'datasheet' and each column takes up the x width for the content. I just made data in 2 other columns longer and the fields expanded exactly as needed.  I must be missing what it is you are trying to do? I just changed my code to spin through the controls AFTER setting all to "-2", and if any exceeded "2000", I reset to "2000". It changed 4 fields for me:     
    RESET 3 ObjectName  From: 2355 to: 2000
    RESET 7 QuerySQL    From: 25440 to: 2000
    RESET 19    Referenced  From: 6525 to: 2000
    RESET 21    Version From: 3900 to: 2000

Comment: Hmm, maybe I am missing something then. :)  When you inspect columnwidths, do you not see the value "-2" vs "2355" per your example?  That's my issue, I see "-2", therefore NONE are > 2000

Comment: Argh, and now its "mostly" working.  Though, I still see a good number of "-2" values.  Not sure the cause.  Anyway, I think I am good for the moment.

Comment: I don't see "-2" -- I see the actual values. From my poorly formatted answer above, I saw: 2355, 25440, 6525, 3900. Just repeated code again to show ALL widths and none are "-2"

Comment: -1 the code doesnt show what Wayne says (if it exceeds...) it just sets the control(7) columnwidth - I could do that too - the real problem is the dynamic clumns that show -2, as numerous comments say and Wayne doesn't answer that

Comment: @johanness that code was an example - I set col 7 to show how it could be done - not as a solution. I updated the code to show how to spin through all columns and reset any > nnn to yyy. And I removed the col 7 example.

Answer (score 1):

Open the affected query(ies) in design view and click and drag to manually resize each column that reports -2 as the column size.  DO NOT double-click to auto-size the column!!! That is what causes the "broken" behavior.

---

Background:

This behavior drove me nuts recently.  I had an AutoFitDatasheet() routine that ran flawlessly for years until one day it stopped working on a specific query.  I used a variant of the following code:

```
MyControl.ColumnWidth = -2
AutoFitColWidth = MyControl.ColumnWidth
```

When this code would run, the first line would tell the control to auto-fit.  The second line would save the column's new width (a positive number).

However, if the column does not need to be resized when assigning the auto-fit property, the ColumnWidth will retain the -2 value it's just been assigned and report that value back when you retrieve the ColumnWidth property.

Exporting the query to text using the undocumented `SaveAsText` routine shows that there is no special "Autofit" property assigned to affected columns.  Rather, the key to reproducing the behavior seems to be how close the starting column width is to the resulting column width following an auto-fit.  An exact match works, but even a value +/- 10 points away from the resized ColumnWidth appears to be enough to trigger the behavior.

I've started using the following code to address the situation, but I have not tested it thoroughly enough to formally recommend it at this time:

```
Const ColumnAutoFit As Long = -2
Dim PrevWidth As Long
PrevWidth = MyControl.ColumnWidth
MyControl.ColumnWidth = ColumnAutoFit
If MyControl.ColumnWidth = ColumnAutoFit Then
    AutoFitColWidth = PrevWidth
Else
    AutoFitColWidth = MyControl.ColumnWidth
End If
```

<del>I should note that I did try assigning a temporary dummy ColumnWidth (e.g., `MyControl.ColumnWidth = 1`) prior to assigning the -2 autofit value.  That did not seem to work, though.</del>

**UPDATE**: In order to make the temporary dummy ColumnWidth work, it has to be a value large enough to prevent the column from being considered hidden.  On my device (running Access 2019), that value was 8.  However, I fear that may be a device-dependent number.  So, to be safe, I used a slightly larger number as my dummy columnwidth (25).

Here's the code I'm using now:

```
Const MinVisibleWidth As Long = 25
.ColumnWidth = MinVisibleWidth

Const ColumnAutoFit As Long = -2
.ColumnWidth = ColumnAutoFit

TotalWidth = TotalWidth + .ColumnWidth
```

Comment: You can see this technique in action as I use it to autofit a datasheet based on the datasheet's contents: [AutoFitDatasheet: A Function to Prettify Your Access Datasheets](https://nolongerset.com/autofitdatasheet/)